# Android app name depends on buildType and flavours Gradle

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, build

Below is an extract from my gradle source code. What I want to achieve is to add suffix to app name when buildType.debug is executed. I tried the following code, but variables are in gradle assigned in sequence as they are written in file and not as task order. So in the example below buildVariant variable will always be equal to Release.

```
{
def buildVariant = ""   
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [showDebug: 'true']
        buildVariant = " (DEBUG)"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [showDebug: 'false']
        signingConfig signingConfigs.myConf
        buildVariant = " Release"
    }
}    
productFlavors {

    flavour1{
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Flavour1'+buildVariant
    }
    flavour2{
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Flavour2'+buildVariant
    }
    flavour3{
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Flavour3'+buildVariant
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a really interesting puzzle to solve, so thanks for the question!

Here what you can do:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ....
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }

        release {
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        FlavorA {
        }

        FlavorB {
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "app_name", '"' + variant.productFlavors.get(0).name + '_' + variant.buildType.name + '"'
    }

}

dependencies {
}
```

As a result, it'd print the app name "FlavorA_debug", "FlavorB_release", etc.

(NB! I ran it with gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' - works great, though I didn't try with older versions)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This piece variant.productFlavors.get(0).name returns flavour name? What if I want a custom flavour name? Lets say that flavour1 has app name MyApp?
Actually my goal is to add Debug suffix only to debug variants. If build variant is release, I want to use just custom flavour's name.

Comment: @urgas9  I see, to make the suffix only for "Debug" buildType, you can modify the applicationVariants.all function like this: applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "app_name", '"' + variant.productFlavors.get(0).name + ((variant.buildType.name=="debug")? " debug" : "") + '"'
    }       For each release build it'd write its Flavor as an app name and for all debug builds - Flavor Name + "Debug" :-)

Comment: Thanks, what about custom flavour name? The problem is, that I am using some special characters for app name (š,ž,..) and i would not like to include them in flavour name (im not sure if that is even supported by gradle), thus i want to make them a custom field

Comment: Just checked "Flavoršž" - works fine. So just give it a try

Comment: Oh, unfortunately this character is too much for gradle: Å. But it works if I save it directly as resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Å'+buildVariant

Comment: I didn't get it. Whad exactly didn't work for you? Flavor "Ålesund_šž" works with my implementation.

Comment: i.e. this works fine:     productFlavors {
        production {
        }

        Ålesund_šž {
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "app_name", '"' + variant.productFlavors.get(0).name + ((variant.buildType.name=="debug")? " debug" : "") + '"'
    }

Comment: The only obvious limitation is that you can't use Cyrillic characters. But then, if you need it - just create various Strings-files for all langs and use them instead of Gradle tricks.     I believe, my answer covers the question you asked.

Comment: well, when trying to build flavour Åpningstider I get this error (Å is transformed to ?): Error:Execution failed for task ':app:merge?pningstiderReleaseResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I am using this gradle dependency: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: Åpningstider fungerer bra for meg :)  [Åpningstider works fine for me]. Only thing - I have to re-compile twice for some reason. I'm running gradle 1.3.0 and 1.5.0 - both work.  I uploaded my simple test app with Åpningstider as a flavor to DropBox - hopefully, it'd help https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wmt7r7duiwozkg/Gradle%20TestApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: oh, weird :D thanks for help, will check the project.

Comment: I was busy, so I didnt have time to check the app you provided. I ran into the issue once again today and Å gets changed to ? for me, even in your app. So the issue must be OS related. Im on Windows 10 with Android Studio 1.5.1, gradle 2.10 and gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta4